# retain and no-retain static route on juniper

Tags: static

I'm learn JNCIS-SP chapter 1 Protocol-Independent Routing. I see a option "retain/no-retain" static route.

I understand If a route configured with option retain so that route will not remove on Forwarding table when the Routing protocol daemon will shutdown.

But what is situation for "retain" option? Because when a device is shutdown => PFE down too?

[retain | Junos OS](https://www.juniper.net/documentation/us/en/software/junos/static-routing/topics/ref/statement/retain-edit-routing-options.html)

Answer (score 5):

JunOS can preserve forwarding table states during RPD or control plane restart/reboot under certain conditions...

This is described in HA module of JNCIS-SP track.
-->> Graceful Restart, GRES and NSR.

The HA module describes the behavior of Graceful Restart of Dynamic Routing Protocols rather than static routes. I suspect this might be a way to preserve that static route active in Forwarding-Table too.

I hope this is helpful.